# Why is this string only returned one time when using LINQ vs Regex?

Tags: c#, regex, string, linq

**EDIT:** *I should have clarified, but I am debugging these two applications in Visual studio. So when I deploy it, one goes to the Rasp Pi (this is the app with the issue), the other is a console app that runs on my local machine.*

I'm not sure of how else to phrase this question, but with your help I'm confident that I can turn it into a more generic question. **At this point I have my project working, but I am unsure of why the way I previously implemented this string parsing did not work. I would like to understand why.**

**Setup:**

I have a console app which I can write a command into, and it sends to an IoT Hub, which my Raspberry Pi then reads, parses the command, and executes a function.

```
        // Keep listening for messages            
        private async Task listenForMessageFromDeviceTask()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var msg =  await AzureIoTHub.ReceiveCloudToDeviceMessageAsync();
                if (msg == null) continue;

                Globals.ParseMsg(msg);
            }
        }
```

**Solution:**

[Link to the current working class on GitHub](https://github.com/DaveVoyles/IoT-NightLight/blob/master/IoTNightLight/Globals.cs)

```
public static void ParseMsg(string msg)
{
    // Split msg on whitespace sequences. 
    // This works great! I only need to retrieve the first word.
    string[] firstWordInMsg = Regex.Split(msg, @"\s+");

        switch (firstWordInMsg[0])
        {
            case "tween":
                // Do something
                break;
            case "stop":
                // Do something
                break;
        }
```

**Problem:**

[Link to the non-working version on GitHub](https://github.com/DaveVoyles/IoT-NightLight/blob/52ebbe82f5d1f09da1d1c9f7d20a171d03ef4e55/IoTNightLight/Globals.cs)

```
public static void ParseMsg(string msg)
{
    // This will only execute ONE time. I can send 10 messages, and it will
    // only receive one. I now have to restart the app, and it can then                  // receive the next message in the queue.
    var first_word = FirstWordFromMessage(msg)

    switch (first_word)
    {
        case "tween":
            // Do something
            break;
        case "stop":
            // Do something
            break;
    }


    public string FirstWordFromMsg(string msg)
    {
    var firstWord = msg.Substring(0, msg.IndexOf(" ", StringComparison.Ordinal));

    return firstWord;
  }
```

**My understanding:**
When I use the first solution, everything plays nice. I can send 10 messages, and the app can read all 10 of them.

With the second implementation, I can only read ONE message before I need to restart the app. At this point, it has 9 more to go through. I then need to quit the app, restart it, and it then has 8 more to go through.

**Why would this happen?**

Comment: Could you create a minimal reproducible example of your application?

Comment: Your second approach will throw an exception if the string contains no spaces.

Comment: It's not clear what your getting at here. *"before I need to restart the app"* are you debugging it??

Comment: Yes @Liam, I should have been clear that I am debugging it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over each message contained in `words`:

```
public static void ParseMsg(string msg)
{
    string[] words = Regex.Split(msg, @"\s+");

    foreach (string word in words)
    {
        switch (word)
        {
            case "tween":
                // Do something
                break;
            case "stop":
                // Do something
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand that if I needed to get every word, this would be the correct way. As it stands, I only need the first word, so the bottom example that I have works correctly. 

I am unsure of why the first solution I offered does not work, however. 

Thank you for this, though!